# How to handle and punish or minimize strange page requests / hack attempts

Tags: php, apache, http-status-code-404

I'm sorry if the title isn't very good, I'm just unable to judge whether the output from my 404 document log are from desperate hackers or desperate spiders. I do send a 404 header, with a courteous message.

The log is there to help me log missing links automatically to track them and fix them. I filter for the 3 paths that have viewable documents in them, but I'd like to know whether there's a best practice, or perhaps a way to delay 404 page loads so I get fewer requests for the filtered out stuff.

I know that I may be talking through my hat here, so just tell me if delays don't punish attackers/spammers (especially if I send a 404 header), if I shouldn't worry at all, or things like that.

It would also be nice to know **which** of these are bona fide hack attempts.

I would like **advice to deal with such in a way that I get less of them, if possible**, rather than [banning IPs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6935394/best-approach-to-handle-attempting-to-hack-a-website).

I'm on a run of the mill shared hosting Apache server with PHP5.

Example output:

```
[2014-05-27 06:03] /browserconfig.xml
[2014-05-27 07:47] /file/jh%27
[2014-05-27 13:25] /?bcsicoach
[2014-05-27 17:52] /wp-login.php
[2014-05-27 18:04] /join.php/join.php
[2014-05-27 18:04] /join.php/join_form.php
[2014-05-27 18:50] /browserconfig.xml
[2014-05-27 20:32] /apple-touch-icon-152x152-precomposed.png
[2014-05-27 20:32] /apple-touch-icon-152x152.png
[2014-05-27 20:32] /apple-touch-icon-precomposed.png
[2014-05-27 20:32] /apple-touch-icon.png
[2014-05-27 22:47] /browserconfig.xml
[2014-05-28 00:07] /apple-touch-icon-76x76-precomposed.png
[2014-05-28 00:07] /apple-touch-icon-76x76.png
[2014-05-28 00:07] /apple-touch-icon-precomposed.png
[2014-05-28 00:07] /apple-touch-icon.png
[2014-05-28 00:07] /apple-touch-icon-precomposed.png
[2014-05-28 00:07] /apple-touch-icon.png
[2014-05-28 05:59] /apple-touch-icon-152x152-precomposed.png
[2014-05-28 06:00] /apple-touch-icon-152x152.png
[2014-05-28 06:00] /apple-touch-icon-precomposed.png
[2014-05-28 06:00] /apple-touch-icon.png
[2014-05-28 06:00] /file/Service.zip
[2014-05-28 08:33] /join.php/join.php
[2014-05-28 08:33] /join.php/join_form.php
[2014-05-28 12:31] /apple-touch-icon.png
[2014-05-28 12:32] /apple-touch-icon.png
[2014-05-28 12:32] /apple-touch-icon.png
[2014-05-28 14:48] /catweasel.jpg
[2014-05-28 14:51] /wp-admin/
[2014-05-28 14:59] /wordpress/wordpress/wp-admin/
[2014-05-28 15:08] /wordpress/wp-admin/
[2014-05-28 15:15] /feed/
[2014-05-28 15:16] /blog/wp-admin/
[2014-05-28 15:25] /wp/wp-admin/
[2014-05-28 15:33] /old/wp-admin/
[2014-05-28 18:44] /wp-admin/
[2014-05-28 18:52] /wordpress/wordpress/wp-admin/
[2014-05-28 18:56] /index.php
[2014-05-28 19:01] /wordpress/wp-admin/
[2014-05-28 19:14] /apple-touch-icon-precomposed.png
[2014-05-28 19:14] /apple-touch-icon.png
[2014-05-28 19:17] /wp/wp-admin/
[2014-05-28 19:25] /old/wp-admin/
```

Comment: The attempts to reach the wordpress admin page are quite obviously from attack bots, trying to hijack the blog / whatever. I wouldn't worry about it, if the page is not full of security holes.

Comment: I'm let down by the cobra reflex downvote 5 seconds after posting. I've waited a bit, but there's no comment after 41 minutes. I'm also let down by the edit and removal of the server environment tags. Should I know not to ask this? Should I provide less information? If so, then provide reasons for that.

Answer (score 0):

Some of those are automated attacks, you could introduce a delay for specific requests, but it won't stop them. The effort to block or introduce a delay would have a negligible affect on the attacker. You shouldn't worry about those requests, since they will happen no matter what you do as long as your website is publicly available. There are tons of people doing those automated attacks, so punishing one person with a delay will not prevent more from coming in from someone else. Same goes for blocking IPs, if you block one IP, another will show up in their place.

The best way to deal with an attack, is to be prepared, keep an eye out for libraries and features that you use on your website to see if they are vulnerable to an attack. Also ensure you are not vulnerable to common attacks like SQL injection, XSS, CSRF, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they are bots and best practises would be to ignore them or let a loadbalanser handle the bot requests.

However if you feel that you want to punish them in a small and childish way; one way would be to alias all the request to a script with a huge timeoute. What such a script will do to your cpu load is another matterand you will have do some testing or read up on the subject.

php example:

```
set_time_limit(999999); // Add a huge amout of seconds to the timeout, if safemode is on this will be ignore and there is no workaround.
sleep(99999); //Hey who said sleep was a no-do :P
echo "ehehehe";
```

Comment: I would strongly recommend AGAINST such an approach. This makes hacking attempt a self-inflicted DDoS.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a handler which would redirect all these requests to http://localhost/$requestedURL

Make sure not to include any real pages from your site in the list though.